# How to condition on one column with different values and print-out paired values in next column in multiple columns?

Tags: oracle

I have a sample date in 'myTable' table, including one column which represents IDs and second column represents their paired values (something like below sample)

myTable

```
IDs    values
0      A+
1      A 
1      D
2      
0      A
2      C
1      
3      C
```

I need to get result as below,

```
0IDs    1IDs    2IDs    3IDs
A+      -       -       -
-       A       -       -
-       D       -       -
-       -       *       -
A       -       -       -
-       -       C       -
-       *       -       -
-       -       -       C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

Data & structure:

```
create table mytable
(
ids number,
vals varchar(5)
);

insert into mytable values(0, 'A+');
insert into mytable values(1, 'A');
insert into mytable values(1, 'D');
insert into mytable values(2, NULL);
insert into mytable values(0, 'A');
insert into mytable values(2, 'C');
insert into mytable values(1, NULL );
insert into mytable values(3, 'C');
```

Test:

```
SQL> select NVL(case when ids=0 then vals else '-' end,'*') as x0IDs,
  2         NVL(case when ids=1 then vals else '-' end,'*') as x1IDs,
  3         NVL(case when ids=2 then vals else '-' end,'*') as x2IDs,
  4         NVL(case when ids=3 then vals else '-' end,'*') as x3IDs
  5  from mytable;

X0IDS X1IDS X2IDS X3IDS
----- ----- ----- -----
A+    -     -     -
-     A     -     -
-     D     -     -
-     -     *     -
A     -     -     -
-     -     C     -
-     *     -     -
-     -     -     C

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```